# How do I install video drivers for my Radeon HD 6450?

Tags: drivers, radeon, ubuntu-studio

Just switched my eMachines PC over to Ubuntu Studio 12.04 in hopes of getting a little bit more out of the dated hardware. I have a HIS Radeon HD 6450 that worked great when the machine was running Windows 7.

With Ubuntu I can't get anything but colored static on the screens. The on-board VGA port works fine for Ubuntu, unless I have the Radeon put in. Is this even compatible? Is there some way to install what I need to make this work? I'm new to Ubuntu, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your BIOS settings may be a place to find a solution. See if there is a way to activate both ports (onboard and external) rather than one or the other. With the monitor attached to the VGA port you should be able to install the correct drivers for your card, to find them visit AMD
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

1: desktop graphics
2: radeon hd series
3: radeon hd 6xxx series pcie
4: linux x86_64

source:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1718183

Answer (score 1):

Video drivers can be insatlled by follow  [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Installing_via_the_command_line) guide or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Manually_installing_Catalyst_13.4)

Comment: best to provide a summary of the info at the links, in case they don't work in the future